# Classifying variable length arrays in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, multinomial

I am stuck with the **classification of an array of signals(ECG) whether the particular segment of the signal is normal or not(having an arrhythmia)**. The segment taken is of variable length(which impacts the classification) and I am not able to do same and getting the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

My training set looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/Pkeundqq); dimensions: 2065 arrays having variable number of elements
and output is like:`array(['N', 'N', 'N', ..., 'N', 'N', 'N'], dtype=object) 2065 long vector`
Y.shape=training_set.shape=2065
I am using Multinomia naive bayes for classification:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(inp, Y)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)`
```

Any hints/advices will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Do this data represent the signals at specific time or intervals?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @VivekKumar , data is time specific

Answer (score 1):

> X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>   Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
>
> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
>   Target values.

Source: [sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.fit)

So you have to adjust your feature vectors (n_samples) to a fixed length (n_features).

Comment: That was what I wanted, I need to classify variable length features, but I don't think it's possible, Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are methods to align time series data to a comparable length (e.g.
 [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)). Furthermore you can use the sum of data points as a single feature.

Comment: Yeah, dynamic time warping can be tried out, however summing the data points is of no use since I need to classify beats which depends on individual signals